# Requesting signed feedback form from end-client

Tags: project-management, feedback

I'm working in the following setup: `Me -> A -> B`. Where `A` is a services company and `B` is the end-client (a product company). There are multiple providers for `A` in the same team, I'm one of them.

There's an entire host of problems but I'll focus on two of them.

This team is managed by a services manager at `A`. This manager is telling me the end client `B` has said my output is much lower than other team members (in terms of ticket count in JIRA). On the other hand my income isn't really where it should be.

Moreover this is pitting me against the other team members in a [Rank & Yank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitality_curve) fashion.

Should I be asking this services manager to provide me signed feedback forms from `B` to certify that the feedback is not made-up and is not word-of-mouth? I had some conversations with this manager and I'm not sure if I should trust them. To be clear, they clearly don't trust me either, so it goes both-ways.

We also have an end-of-day meeting with the team where nothing gets written down. I'm also considering communicating that I won't be attending that meeting and instead would rather receive a written summary of that meeting because nothing of substance is being discussed there. Everything is already in JIRA.

If I keep attending this meeting, I'm considering asking every time if everything is good on my side because all metrics KPIs, OKRs are somewhat concealed from me and there's no way for me to easily check if my output is good or bad. The way these are measured, compared or judged is just opaque and it's generating anxiety on my part on whether I'll get my last invoice paid or not or how much time this contract will last for me.

Comment: That seems to be an exceptionally shitty job, just from your prelude to the actual question. We won't be able to advise you on anything that would make your pay difference or the  stack ranking go away. Is there any reason you are staying there?

Comment: Yes, I'm giving them the benefit of doubt, maybe I am a complete idiot and don't know what I'm talking about or don't understand what's going on. At the same time, new offers don't come at the snap of a finger, interviews would take time and would shift my focus from the actual work I'm performing for both `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 7):

> Should I be asking this services manager to provide me signed feedback
> forms from B to certify that the feedback is not made-up and is not
> word-of-mouth?

Not if you value your job.

> I'm also considering communicating that I won't be attending that
> meeting and instead would rather receive a written summary of that
> meeting because nothing of substance is being discussed there.

Is that how it works in this company? Folks can just decide on their own that they aren't going to attend a team meeting?

I've never worked on that sort of team.

> I had some conversations with this manager and I'm not sure if I
> should trust them. To be clear, they clearly don't trust me either, so
> it goes both-ways.

Sounds like a toxic situation. Trust is important. Perhaps you should be looking for a new job.

Comment: I'd suggest elaborating on at least the first part of your answer. While I generally agree with the points made in this answer, it doesn't really do much to explain *why* some of the OP's ideas might be an issue/*how* they don't actually solve OP's problems.

Comment: Re: Is that how it works in this company? : I've since cancelled my attendance to the daily meeting at the end of each day.